# Grails: Printing how long each request took

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to print for each request in my controllers, when the request started, when it ended and how long was the process. Do i have to add this code to each request separately or is there any generic way to do that?

Comment: For something quick and simple have you looked at the Profiler plugin? http://grails.org/plugin/profiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the wide variety of plugins that exist ([Profiler](http://grails.org/plugin/profiler) for example) a very simple solution is to use a filter. This [blog post](http://techbeats.deluan.com/profiling-web-requests-in-your-grails-application/) walks you through the process of setting up a filter that will log the start and end times for each controller action.

A very simple example using a Grails filter would be:

```
class PerfFilter {
  def filters = {
    profiler(controller: '*', action: '*') {
      before {
        request._startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        log.trace("Beginning ${controllerName} ${actionName}")
      }
      after {
        log.trace("Finished ${controllerName} ${actionName}")
        log.trace("Total time to execute was: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - request._startTime}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need something more robust for overall performance monitoring I highly recommend the [Javamelody plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody) for Grails.

Comment: Can i store state in filters? For example, can i store the time in 'before' and use if in 'after'?

Comment: You sure can. You can add it into the parameter map, request scope, flash scope, any number of ways. E.g. in before `request._timeBeforeRequest = System.currentTimeMillis()` The blog post I linked to has an example of this.

Comment: Updated the example in my answer to include showing the total time to execute the controller's action.

Answer (score 0):

apache AB helps immensely. You can do an ab test with one concurrency and one request to just show the time if need be. I'd also suggest a tool called 'New Relic'. Great for testing and shows time for request and bottlenecks.